# Trying to delete duplicate rows... syntax help requested

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
DELETE FROM LIM_STAGE.RESULTS A 
WHERE ROWID > ( SELECT min(1) 
                FROM LIM_STAGE.RESULTS B
                WHERE A.result_number = B.result_number );
```

This code returns error 
   Error 
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected ROWID got NUMBER

And I am not sure how to alter it to get the results needed.

It seems where I have the numeral 1 should be something else, but I cannot figure out how to actually establish the individual row numbers.

Appreciate help getting rid of these duplicate rows.  This is a large table with many indexes, and triggers... hate to hae to rewrite everything.

Thank you for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
delete from lim_stage.results
where rowid not in (
    select min(rowid)
    from lim_stage.results
    group by result_number
)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Perculating right along. The statement launched two long-ops and they both now show 100%.  Must be in final stages, but that could take forever.  Not a direct connection.

Comment: you could probably make it perform a bit better by replacing the NOT IN with the NOT EXISTS syntax.

Comment: Depending on what the triggers do, you could consider turning them off, as context switching can greatly increase the time it takes to process your statement.